# External Hard Drive Operating System

Tags: windows, ubuntu

If I put a OS onto a External hard drive, would it allow viruses to infect my internal hard drive?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Security.SE. I see you tried to make an edit as an anonymous user. Please log in to the same account that you used to post this, then your edit will go through.

Answer (score 1):

## **Yes.**

An Operating System on an External Drive can have the same access to your system as your installed system. The reverse, your installed infecting your external system may also be possible.

Comment: Reverse is only true if you don't remove external drive and it has a file system understood by Windows. Ubuntu's default file system is ext4 and not readable by Windows

Comment: @NeilSmithline That a file system on the external drive is not readable by Windows does not prevent malware from doing whatever it wants with the drive.

Comment: @Neil Smithline I never thought about that. Thanks!